# Possibly Incorrect Reopen review audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I just failed this audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3259718

It was marked closed as "unclear what you're asking". That's not so; the question is perfectly clear. However, it is asking for answerers to "find a ... specific off site resource". Thus the question should be closed.

Is my reasoning wrong? Alternatively, are we supposed to reopen and then reclose questions using the correct reason? ([Robert Harvey's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160419/191706) suggests that doing so is discouraged.)

Comment: Tricky; it's obviously a tool that others use, and the documentation between versions may have changed.  Is that interpretation of the rule too literal?  I wonder.

Comment: As a review audit, it is not ideal.  My interpretation is it is nothing more than a request for an external resource, so should be closed as such.

Comment: @Makoto raises a good point. However, my understanding - which may well be wrong - was that audits are supposed to be immediately obvious, with the goal of catching robo-reviewers rather than educating users on edge cases.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName That's the goal, but audits are selected by an alogorithm so you are always going to have problem questions regardless of the algorithm.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm aware; that's why I posted on meta: so inappropriately selected audits can be removed from circulation (or I can be told why it's a good audit and I should have reopened it).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I'm trying to find the link, but I can't at the moment.  But it has been stated several times that the best way to ensure a close/reopen post is not used in the future is to take the opposite action (so vote to close outside the queue and it won't get selected again)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Didn't know about that, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misquoting that off-topic reason. It reads:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Note that the word "specific" doesn't appear anywhere - indeed, a big problem with the questions this reason was created to address is that they're *not* specific, thus opening the door to lazy recommendations and spam. Indeed, the advice [linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) is *all about* being more specific as to the problem being solved.

The question used in this audit isn't asking for folks to recommend their favorite Font Awesome reference - it's just looking for the canonical docs for a specific version of the software, and includes specific details as to where that documentation *used to* be found and how it's failing now. It seems *quite* specific.

While that might seem like an odd question to ask, it's more common than you might realize: [some companies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203147/a-question-requesting-for-official-api-documentation-url-counts-as-off-topic/203153#203153) are, sadly, *crap* at maintaining stable links to stuff like this.

As such, there's only really one possible answer - thus eliminating the problems of subjectiveness and spam-attraction inherent in "recommendation" questions.

Comment: I disagree that there's only one possible answer, as *any* external link to *any* mirror of the docs answers the question, and it's essentially asking for a link only answer. But certainly "what JavaScript library should I use for drag and drop" this ain't.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Similar question, tons of votes, high number of views.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn/820444#820444

Comment: @JoshC Those don't make it a good, on-topic question. Also, it's from 2009, when question standards were a lot different.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I agree - it wasn't a good question. But technically neither of them are **recommendations**.

Comment: @JoshC You've linked a question that's too broad and asks several implementation/usage/TOS questions; the audit question asks for a link to some documentation. I fail to understand the relevance of your example, as the questions are substantially different. The fact that the top answers on both are piles of links isn't relevant.

Comment: The title of that question was a bit misleading, @Esoteric - jQuery UI is a collection of scripts, plugins, and CSS themes; the confusion arose then because linking to these is slightly less trivial than just using the base library (for which the URLs are well-documented and widely used).

Comment: I think the word "recommendation" is muddying things, so I have edited it out of the question. The relevant portion of the close reason is "find a specific off site resource". Certainly this question would be useful to future visitors looking for that documentation, and also certainly it clearly requests that someone locate a specific off site resource. If it's on topic (I don't know if it is or not at this point; I just think it's not a helpful audit), then perhaps the close reason wording should be changed?

Comment: See my edit, @Esoteric.

Comment: @ShogDYIN' You're right, thanks for clearing that up.